# Lotus note: search mail by recipient

Tags: email, search, lotus-notes

My company use Lotus Notes 8.5
I want to search by recipient, I'm in several email group and I'd like to know if a mail is address directly to me or to a group.

I know the search by field but I already:
 `recipient contains groupMail@domain.com` and
`ToName contains groupMail@domain.com` 
 and it's definitely not working. 
Is it possible ? or just a foolish dream ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: You can mark every mail with a little circle to indicate, if a mail is sent directly to you or to a group. Go to `More -> Preferences -> Mail -> Attention Indicators` and check the appropriate checkmarks under "Recipient indicators".

But that was not your question. There are three fields containing recipient information: 
SendTo, CopyTo and BlindCopyTo. 
The "shortest" search would be:

```
[SendTo] = "groupmail@domain.com" or [CopyTo] = "groupmail@domain.com" or [BlindCopyTo] = "groupmail@domain.com"
```

= and contains are the same in the search string.

Take care: Searches in fields only work, if your admin has created a fulltext- index for your database. If he didn't -> Don't blame Notes for it...

Comment: I love you, and I hate definitely lotus notes